# How to select a node's attribute if the value containing symbol ' and "?

Tags: c#, xpath, symbols

For example the xml is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Test>
  <TestNode index = "A's B"s">ABCDEFG</TestNode>
</Test>
```

Normally I try the following code in C# to get the Node:

```
XmlDocument doc= new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("xxx.xml");
string xpath = string.Format("//TestNode[@index='{0}']", "A's B\"s");
XmlNode TestNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

The code gets the error because the xpath will become "//TestNode[@index='A's B\"s"

Although I can use " instead of ' to indicate the value, just say

```
string xpath = string.Format("//TestNode[@index=\"{0}\"]", "A's B\"s");
```

However the code also gets the error because the value contains "

So what should I do if I want to select the node that its attribute value contains both ' and " ?

Comment: The example is not valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

mladenp's blog entry describes a number of options for correctly XMLEncoding: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx